# JPA 2.0 : NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getCache()Ljavax/persistence/Cache

Tags: jpa-2.0, weblogic-10.x, cassandra-2.0, kundera

I am trying to run my spring based web-application on Weblogic 10.3.6. This application uses Apache Cassandra version 2.0.7 for storing/accessing data.

We are using JPA 2.0 with a persistence.xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd" version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="cassandra">
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra"/>
            <property name="cql.version" value="3.0.0"/>
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory"/>

            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="abc"/>
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost"/>
            <property name="kundera.port" value="9160"/>
            <property name="kundera.ddl.auto.prepare" value="validate"/>

        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I have also applied the JPA 2.0 patch in Weblogic 10.3.6 by modifying the commEnv.sh file as below:

```
# Enable JPA2.0 support
PRE_CLASSPATH="${PRE_CLASSPATH}:${MW_HOME}/modules/com.oracle.jpa2support_1.0.0.0_2-1.jar:${MW_HOME}/modules/javax.persistence_1.1.0.0_2-0-0.jar"
export PRE_CLASSPATH
```

The application is deployed successfully but while trying to access the back-end via EntityManager, I see an error as follows:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory.getCache()Ljavax/persistence/Cache;
        at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.<init>(EntityManagerImpl.java:128)
        at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:246)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

The relevant entries in the pom file are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>kundera-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.impetus.kundera.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>kundera-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.11</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone please help by suggesting what can be wrong here?

Regards,

Anand

Answer (score 0):

Please remove following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

After that it should work.